# Zend framework amazon S3 - How to store file as reduced redundancy?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

The zend framework provides a  php wrapper for the amazon S3 api that simplifies the lower level REST functionality.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html

For example to store a file in s3 all you need to do is

```
$s3->putFile("me.png", "my-own-bucket/Pictures/Me.png",
    array(Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER =>
          Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ));
```

By default, objects are stored in buckets as regular storage.  Is there any functionality in the zend framework that will allow me specify objects to be stored as Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) in S3?

If not is there any way I can set the default storage of all objects in a bucket as RRS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Have you tried the following after RockyFords advice?
The code below should upload it in the correct mode.

```
$s3->putFile("me.png", "my-own-bucket/Pictures/Me.png",
    array(
        Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER => Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
        'x-amz-storage-class' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can pass a third argument to `Zend_Services_S3::putFile and putObject` that is `$meta` and it accepts a scalar or an array.

```
public function putFile($path, $object, $meta=null)
    {
        $data = @file_get_contents($path);
        if ($data === false) {
            /**
             * @see Zend_Service_Amazon_S3_Exception
             */
            require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/S3/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3_Exception("Cannot read file $path");
        }

        if (!is_array($meta)) {
            $meta = array();
        }

        if (!isset($meta[self::S3_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER])) {
           $meta[self::S3_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER] = self::getMimeType($path);
        }

        return $this->putObject($object, $data, $meta);
    }
```

and S3 just wants a header change to set an object or file as RRS:

> Q: How do I specify that I want to store my data using RRS?
>
> All objects in Amazon S3 have a storage class setting. The default
>   setting is STANDARD.  You can use an optional header on a PUT request
>   to specify the setting REDUCED_REDUNDANCY.

you may have to dig in the API a bit to find exactly what to pass, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the lead Rocky, but I was unable to find a way to store the file as rrs.

Answer (score 0):

If you get following error . simple increase file upload size in php.ini . default is 2 mb increase by 20mb or as per your requirement .

```
 Error follows...
 Exception: Zend_Service_Amazon_S3_Exception
 Message: Cannot read file 
 Trace: #0 /var/www/html/cabapp/src/cabapp-cms/application/modules/default/controllers/DriverController.php(495): Zend_Service_Amazon_S3->putFile('', 'driver-license/...', Array)
 #1 /var/www/html/cabapp/src/cabapp-cms/application/modules/default/controllers/DriverController.php(640): DriverController->_saveDriver()
 #2 /var/www/html/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): DriverController->addeditAction()
 #3 /var/www/html/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('addeditAction')
 #4 /var/www/html/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
 #5 /var/www/html/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(101): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
 #6 /var/www/html/cabapp/src/lib/Ripple/Application/AbstractApplication.php(274): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
 #7 /var/www/html/cabapp/src/cabapp-cms/cabapp-cms.php(33): Ripple\Application\AbstractApplication->run()
 #8 /var/www/html/cabapp/src/cabapp-cms/application/webroot/index.php(44): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')
 #9 {main}
```